# I am trying to install eclipse in my windows system, I am unable to install due to an issue

Tags: windows, eclipse

I am trying to install eclipse neon package in my windows system.

i have downloaded successfully, but, while i am trying to install it's showing a message.I am unable to install eclipse.

I am sharing error image: 
[image]

Comment: You're using an (old) 64-bit Eclipse with what looks like a 32-bit Java runtime. They have to match.

Comment: yes...my issue has been resolved ..thankyou